# Error while Foreman install on Centos 7

Tags: puppet, theforeman

Unable to install Foreman on a new `VM`. I get the following error on `Centos 7`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#foreman-installer --enable-foreman-proxy
```

> /
>   Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[lab-puppet01.myhost.com]:
>   Could not evaluate: Proxy lab-puppet01.myhost.com cannot be registered
>   (Could not load data from https://lab-puppet01.myhost.com  /
>   Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[lab-puppet01.myhost.com]:
>   Failed to call refresh: Proxy lab-puppet01.myhost.com cannot be
>   registered (Could not load data from https ://lab-puppet01.myhost.com 
>   /
>   Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[lab-puppet01.myhost.com]:
>   Proxy lab-puppet01.myhost.com cannot be registered (Could not load
>   data from https ://lab-puppet01.myhost.com

Comment: What happens if you visit the address https://lab-puppet01.myhost.com/ ?  Or run `curl -k https://lab-puppet01.myhost.com/` ?  Ensure the name is in DNS, not /etc/hosts.

Comment: I get the following from curl -k https://lab-puppet01.myhost.com/ : Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/share/foreman/tmp/cache/websockets_ssl_key20160530-15163-1h5couw (Errno::EACCES)
  /opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/ruby/tempfile.rb:136:in `initialize'
  /opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/ruby/tempfile.rb:136:in `open'
  /opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/ruby/tempfile.rb:136:in `block in initialize'
  /opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/ruby/tmpdir.rb:129:in `create'
  /opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/share/ruby/tempfile.rb:133:in `initialize'

Comment: Check everything is up to date with a `yum upgrade`, it ought to work after the 1.11.2 release on an up to date EL7 box. If not, you can disable SELinux by running both `setenforce 0` and changing enforcing to permissive in /etc/sysconfig/selinux.

Comment: Thank you, @m0dlx ! yum update fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I have solved the issue. Thanks to @m0dlx for pointing me in the right direction. Following steps fixed my problem, and foreman installed successfully.
1. run yum update
2. yum remove puppet and puppet-server
3. Follow the installation instruction from http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.11/index.html#2.1Installation for Centos 7.